# How to create custom tableview cells in iPad?

Tags: ipad

My requirement is to create a tableview cell which holds two touch event in a single cell, I have no idea how to create two separate touch events in a single cell, one in the left and one in the right of each cell, when I tap right portion it navigate the correspondent page, when I tap the left portion of the cell it navigate its correspondent page.how to do two touch events in a single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [this tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/) which covers the creating custom tableview cells. Though It is for iPhone there is not much difference except the size of the tableviewcell.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is a great tutorial ,but my need is somewhat different,i want to show two news topic in a single cell,the user tap the right side cells news topic it navigate the corespondent news page,like visversa.any idea about this?

Comment: @nipin You have to modify that yourself according to your requirement. This tutorial gives you base how you create custom cell. Now what you put in that and iterate depends on your requirement. Try it out it is not so hard. I am sure you can do this if you learned from tutorial. Thax.